# What is the meaning of "from overwhelm to whelm".

Tags: meaning

Kindly exlpain the phrase "from overwhelm to whelm" from the following sentence.

"In future we'll have new services to help us bring that universe from overwhelm to whelm". 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-future-of-email-as-far-as-business-communication-is-concerned

My research showed that this is not a set expression. The word "whelm" means  to turn upside down or to overcome in thought or feeling. The main definition of the verb overwhelm is to affect (someone) very strongly. But still have no glue about the sentence in general.

Comment: It's not supposed to be a "grammatical" usage - it's just a bit of wordplay loosely "punning" on the fact that e-communications (particularly, *spam* and such) are becoming ***overwhelming***, whereas to most people there is no such word as ***whelm***. The writer is thus "inventing" a neologism that's intended to be the opposite of *overwhelm*. He's probably unaware that plain *whelm* is effectively just the obsolete version of *overwhelm*, but that doesn't matter if his *readers* are either also unaware, or prepared to overlook that minor discrepancy anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made this a bit easier now) So does that mean that future services will help us to make e-communications more supportable? or should I use any other words?

Comment: *You* can use whatever words you like to convey whatever *you* want to say. I'm just telling you why that blogger used the term "from overwhelm to whelm" even though superficially it's just gibberish. I didn't read the entire blog post, but I'd have to say *making e-comms more **supportable*** is unlikely/weird phrasing. Better would be ***manageable*** (or perhaps ***bearable*** or similar).

Comment: Echoing @Fumblefingers: the author seems to suggest that the new services will change that universe from *overwhelming* to merely *whelming* -- something we can deal with rather than something we can only stare at helplessly.

Comment: A similar play on words I've heard is "underwhelm," meaning that whatever the subject is, you were less than impressed with it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Actually, there *is* a difference in the two words.  "Overwhelm" means to "bury or drown beneath a huge mass" while "whelm" means to "engulf, submerge, or bury".  So the implication is one of going from something that is mind-bogglingly unmanageable to something that is merely suffocating.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Well, the full OED gives no less than 11 different definitions for ***whelm***, but almost all of them are explicitly marked either "obsolete" or "dialectal", and none have citations later than C19. So all we really have is that the surviving form is an *emphatic* version (purely by virtue of the ***over*** prefix, I'm sure). I doubt OP's cited writer knew or cared about what if anything the earlier form *might* have meant - he just "reverse-engineered" from the word he *did* know, to remove the emphasis (which as StoneyB says, gives the sense he meant, regardless of dictionaries).

Answer (score -1):

Well, obviously "overwhelm" refers to being buried or drowning in something that we feel is beyond us such as the "universe" that the site refers to. To "whelm" is to overcome a situation or  the difficulties we face in handling the situation. So basically, what the site implies is that new communication services in the future will help us go from not being able to handle the situation/s to becoming able to overcome the situation and understand it. Hope this helps

Comment: Where did you get that definition of "whelm"?